# URL Rewrite: redirect from one page to another

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all request for `https://www.example.com/about` to `https://www.anotherexample.com`. The following rewrite rule does not work.

```
<rule name="RULENAME"  stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^about" ignoreCase="true" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.anotherexample.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Both sites are WordPress sites. What am I missing?

EDIT 1

I notice that if my match url is `<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />`, when i access `example.com`, it correctly redirects, but `example.com/about` does not

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I tested your rule it is working correctly. could you please provide some example of what is your exact requirement? what result did you get when you try to access the https://www.example.com/about

Comment: @JalpaPanchal when i access example.com/about, it does not redirect.

Comment: so you also want to redirect https://www.example.com/about and https://www.example.com? did you try to run frt as lex li suggested? this is the result of your rule [img](https://i.imgur.com/iwej9rx.png) you could also try to clear browser history

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I just enabled frt but see no reference of my rule in the request trace

Comment: could you share your web.config file? did you enable the rewrite rule at the folder level or site level?